# Count number of characters between two specific characters in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract the date into a new column from a column containing a string in a dataframe using Python.

The field always starts with [SOME_TEXT]_DD/MM/YYYY

SOME_TEXT is of variable length

The characters [ and ] may or may not appear again later in the string

I am able to extract the date where [SOME_TEXT]_ is 18 characters long like this:-

df['date'] = MID(df['Column_with_date'],18,10)

So I figure if I know the length of [SOME_TEXT] I can adapt the above line.

How can I calculate the length of [SOME_TEXT]?

Comment: does the SOME_TEXT that appears before date always be between [ and ] and is it always in the beginning of the field? Some more examples of the field will make this question more readable and understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str.extract` for a regex option:

```py
df["date"] = df["Column_with_date"].str.extract(r'\[.*?\]_(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})')
```

If additionally you want the `date` column to be a bona fide datetime column rather than text, then use `pd.to_datetime()`:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. And is a more elegant solution than counting chars.